# Algorithms for edge-routing given pixel locations of nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph

What are some algorithms for generating edges to various nodes in a graph that minimize edge overlap with nodes and other edges?

Basically, say I have a bunch of boxes (with widths, heights, xs, ys) on a canvas and I want to draw edges between several of them. Furthermore, the edges must connect to points on the boxes at specific points (ie, at exactly 5px from the top of the left edge).

I feel like this is an optimization problem that others have thought about before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're interested in computing and minimizing the graph crossing number. It is an NP-Hard problem, [here's](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/download/DS21/pdf) a not-so-old survey of this problem and [Helena's Master's thesis](http://www.dcs.fmph.uniba.sk/diplomovky/obhajene/getfile.php/dipl.pdf?id=137&fid=223&type=..) is a comprehensive start to the analysis of algorithms for the graph crossing number problem.

Comment: Ah ... thanks! I guess we'll have to use an approximation.